# How to build a dashed line that has borders on both sides, using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 circles, between them I had used `<hr/>` for dashed lines.

```
<td >
 <asp:Image ID="grrenimg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images1/" />
 </td>
 <td>
   <hr class="dashed-lines" style=""/>
 </td>
 <td style="width: 2%">
 <asp:Image ID="redimg" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images2" />
 </td>
```

I need something like this:

[image]

Comment: ooh, don't use table for layout - they should only be used for tabular data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#Line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed white;
  display: block;
}

#LineWrapper {
  background: gray;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
   position: relative;
   top: 50px;
}

#LineWrapper::after {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    left: -6px;
    top: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#LineWrapper::before {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    right: -6px;
    top: -10px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="LineWrapper">
<span id="Line"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks men....will it work for dynamic data..I mean Color Red and Green will based on some values.

Comment: I used `after before` and it's hard to control those with dynamic data, this [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/bwsjsy6m/) will better for you.